# What is causing the warning "no return, in function returning non-void"?

Tags: c++, eclipse

I am not sure why Eclipse is reporting no return value.  Shouldn't it know that I am either returning a value or throwing, thus no need for the warning?

```
class PropertyCollection : public PersistentObject
{
  private:
    std::map<const bmd2::string, bmd2::string> container;

  public:
    bmd2::string & operator[](const bmd2::string & s) throw (CustomException);
};


bmd2::string & operator[](const bmd2::string & s) throw (CustomException)
{
  try
  {
    return container.at(s);
  }
  catch (std::out_of_range & e) {
    throw CustomException();
  };
}
```

Comment: So it's just Eclipse's lint, and not the compiler? Sounds like a bug in Eclipse's lint.

Comment: That's not a compiler error, is it? Eclipses code analyzer is not the smartest kid in the block.

Comment: Is that the whole error message? Is it pointing to a specific function or line?

Comment: That is the entire error message and it is pointing to the line itself... specifically ONLY the return type.  How can I see if it's eclipse lint versus compiler?

Comment: It is a Codan warning, if that helps.

Comment: I've seen this before, just wish I could find the dupe of it. Identical symptoms as well. Their's was worse, because to "solve" it a dummy return was put in after the catch block, and a different tool id'ed it as unreachable. T'was a good question.

Comment: Nothing to do with the question, but if you're coming from the Java world, please don't use exception specifications in C++. They're useless.

Comment: Yeah, most people on SO tell me not to use them.  We are using them ... solely as a form of documentation; that is, so a programmer can look at our code and see which functions throw which exceptions that we've declared.

Comment: @jakeliquorblues please don't. Just use a comment for that. You don't gain anything by using exception specifications (and in fact, they're deprecated in C++11)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a semi-colon after the `catch` block (it is not syntactically necessary):

```
bmd2::string & operator[](const bmd2::string & s) throw (CustomException)
{
  try
  {
    return container.at(s);
  }
  catch (std::out_of_range & e) {
    throw CustomException();
  };                                  // <--- Semicolon not needed
}
```

The compiler may be telling you, therefore, that the null statement is not a return statement, so that execution falls off the end of the function without returning a value.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is indeed correct. There is no code path that could reach the end of the function before returning (throwing will cause the function to return).

Eclipses code analyzer simply does not see that (it's not the only piece of valid code that the analyzer will fail to understand, you'll see). Best solution (aside from fixing eclipse, which may be quite a bit of work) in my opinion would be to simply disable this particular rule from code analyzer preferences. While it may be useful to know that you've forgotten to return from a code path, it's not worth the false positives. Besides, the compiler should warn you about those anyway as long as the warnings are enabled.

A bit off topic, please read [this](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill22.htm) about exception specifiers.

Comment: I have a const and a non-const version.  I simply made a copy-paste error.  So I actually get two annoying errors instead of one!  I fixed my question to show the same declarations.

Comment: Ok, I removed that note from the answer as it no longer applies.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to disable the rule, a *silly* workaround (that might result in warnings about dead code from the compiler's lint though) is adding a `return` at the end of the function, after the end of the catch... block.

It will shut Eclipse up, and will not harm the end result, but it's good to comment on it to avoid bafflement when analyzing the code later.

```
bmd2::string & operator[](const bmd2::string & s) throw (CustomException)
{
  try
  {
    return container.at(s);
  }
  catch (std::out_of_range & e) {
    throw CustomException();
  };
  return container.at(s); //won't happen, added just to silence Eclipse's warnings.
}
```